# Does urlencode() protect against XSS

Tags: php, xss

`$address` and `$cityState` is user provided, stored in a DB, and available for others to view as shown below.  Is there risk of [XSS](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)? Should `htmlspecialchars()` also be used on it?

```
<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:blue|<?php echo(urlencode($address.' '.$cityState));?>&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=400x400&amp;sensor=false" alt="Map" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no **magic wand** PHP function what will protect you from all. Every protection is 100% safe till day it hacked. You just need to understand from where and how your site can be hacked and improve your protection every day.

You can get some interesting tips from [article about XSS prevention](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Also from [php.net urlencode documentation](http://php.net/urlencode):

```
<?php
$query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `htmlspecialchars` should also be used - you're first encoding the URL to be URL-safe, and then you're building it into an HTML-attribute, which 'requires' the HTML-style escaping.

After using both encodings it's no longer possible to inject arbitrary code on *your* end of the scale, so if any risks remain they're on Google's end. As such you can then consider this code safe.

Comment: Thanks Niels.  So, do `urlencode()` first? For instance `htmlspecialchars(urlencode($badString))`

Comment: Yes, first encode the URL so it is safe on its own (and especially the space is correctly encoded), then encode it so it's fit for embedding into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`urlencode()` should not be used for protection from XSS. `htmlspecialchars()` is the way to go, but you are never safe.