# How can avoid wrong GET request caused by "+" symbol?

Tags: php, get

My URL path:

```
https://mypage/main.php?dir=farm/1234_animal_fred+sam_cats
```

I am requesting the data with the GET method:

```
$dir = $_GET['dir'];
echo $dir;
```

But my result is

```
farm/1234_animal_fred sam_cats
```

Comment: don't use `+` in your url but `%2B` instead; https://mypage/main.php?dir=farm/1234_animal_fred%2Bsam_cats

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: How is the `1234_animal_fred+sam_cats` part produced in the first place?

Comment: @Mike Well it is from a database of millions of file paths, so I do not have influence on the path name

Comment: Please set the question as done, or delete it or close it.

Comment: @Unex But I am still in a discussion with some users.

Comment: The reason I ask is that there might be some other characters in there that don't do what you think when passing them in a URL. Just encode the file path part of the URL using `urlencode`. Don't encode the whole URL as Wolf Vos's answer suggests because it won't work.

Comment: @Mike Yes, there might be more characters that will cause problems. I will give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though Unex's answer is right in this particular case, I am unsure if he would be missing other characters that may be in your DB that could cause something to fail, or worse yet, open you up to an XSS vulnerability. So instead of making it work in this one single case by doing:

```
$url = str_replace('+', '%2B', $url);
```

You want to instead make it work for *all* cases. So assuming you have the following from your database:

```
$file_path = 'farm/1234_animal_fred+sam_cats';
```

To make this work correctly as part of a URL you need to do `urlencode()`, however from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338398/811240) you will notice that it's not enough to protect you from XSS attacks. You therefore also need to use `htmlspecialchars()` on the string:

```
$url = 'https://mypage/main.php?dir=';
$file_path = 'farm/1234_animal_fred+sam_cats';
$url .= htmlspecialchars(urlencode($file_path));

echo $url; // https://mypage/main.php?dir=farm%2F1234_animal_fred%2Bsam_cats
```

And when going to this URL you can see that PHP gets the correct value:

```
print_r($_GET) output:
Array
(
    [dir] => farm/1234_animal_fred+sam_cats
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

don't use `+` in your url but `%2B` instead;

This is the result :

`https://mypage/main.php?dir=farm/1234_animal_fred%2Bsam_cats`

hope this helped,

Comment: this is my comment

Answer (score -2):

You should always use **raw**urlencode($url) to encode your urls.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Credits go to commenters, sorry guys I was to quick to respond.

Comment: No! You _can not_ encode a URL with that function! The function allows to encode strings such that they can be used _inside_ a URL. That is a _huge_ difference!

Comment: Nope, you should `never` encode the url with `urlencode` :)

Comment: @arkascha So it is just totally impossible to use `+` inside the URL?

Comment: @Jarla Certainly a `+` can be used inside a URL, but it has a special meaning. Just as a `/` for example. If you want to place the _literal character `+`_ inside a URL, then you have to encode it.

Comment: It is possible, use [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php), as suggested by @Mike in the main thread, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Eihwaz: If I understood you right I just write `echo rawurlencode($dir);` and the result will be `farm/1234_animal_fred+sam_cats`

Comment: Hm, no understood it wrong, I get the result `farm%1234_animal_fred%sam_cats`

Comment: @Jarla I guess you have to use rawurldecode($_GET['dir']) to restore the + sign in your code.

Comment: @WolfVos no, same result: `farm%1234_animal_fred%sam_cats`